# Limiting SQL Results Based on Date

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I'm not too familiar with the types of operations possible on SQL queries.

There's a line in the query that returns a value:

```
    trunc(sysdate) - trunc(\"DATE\") AS days_ago
```

I'm wondering if there's any way to have the query avoid returning any rows where 'days_ago' is greater than 365?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add this to your query:

```
WHERE (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(\"DATE\"))<=365;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason adding this to the WHERE clause won't work:

`WHERE (trunc(sysdate) - trunc(\"DATE\")) <= 365`

?

You could also set a variable equal to trunc(sysdate) - trunc(\"DATE\") and perform your WHERE condition against that variable